# Markov inequality application: is this correct?

Tags: probability

For a uniformly distributed random variable $X$ in $[0,4]$, the mean of $X$ is obviously $2$. So by Markov inequality $Pr(X>1)\le 2$. The right hand side or the inequality is not a probability, What does this mean?

Comment: It means that in this case the Markov inequality unfortunately doesn't provide you with any useful information.

Comment: It is correct, but not very useful. The RHS does not have to be a probability, it is just an upper bound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Markov inequality (is of course correct but), in the present case, yields a trivial upper bound. Actually, this inequality is useful to bound the probabilities of *deviations*. Here $X\gt1$ is not a deviation since $1\lt E(X)=2$.

Assume by contrast that one is interested in bounding  $P(X\lt1)$, then $[X\lt1]\subset[|X-E(X)|\gt1]$ and Markov inequality applied to $|X-E(X)|$ yields
$$P(|X-E(X)|\gt1)\leqslant E(|X-E(X)|).$$
Unfortunately, $|X-E(X)|$ is uniform on $(0,2)$ hence $E(|X-E(X)|)=1$ and one gets the still trivial upper bound $$P(|X-E(X)|\gt1)\leqslant1.$$
But... it happens that $[|X-E(X)|\gt1]=[|X-E(X)|^a\gt1]$ for every $a\gt0$ hence  Markov inequality applied to $|X-E(X)|^a$ yields
$$P(|X-E(X)|\gt1)\leqslant E(|X-E(X)|^a).$$ The same argument as before yields $E(|X-E(X)|^a)=2^a/(a+1)$. This is minimum for $a+1=1/\log2$, and yields $$P(|X-E(X)|\gt1)\leqslant\frac12\mathrm e\log2\approx0.94,$$
far from optimal, but at least less than $1$... :-)

To still refine this, note that $[X\lt1]=[\mathrm e^{-tX}\gt\mathrm e^{-t}]$ for every $t\gt0$ hence Markov inequality applied to $\mathrm e^{-tX}$ (which is often called Chebyshev exponential inequality) yields $$P(X\lt1)\leqslant\mathrm e^tE(\mathrm e^{-tX})=\frac1{4t}(\mathrm e^t-\mathrm e^{-3t}).
$$
For example, for $t=1$, one gets
$$
P(X\lt1)\leqslant\frac1{4}(\mathrm e-\mathrm e^{-3})\approx0.67,
$$
which is slightly better (but still far from the true value $0.25$).